# How to Create a String From Iterator in Python?

Tags: python, string, iterator

**How to create a string from an iterator over string in Python?**

I am currently just trying to create a reversed copy of a string, I know I could just use slice:

```py
s = 'abcde'
reversed_s = s[::-1]
```

I could also create a list from the iterator and join the list:

```py
s = 'abcde'
reversed_s_it = reversed(s)
reversed_list = list(reversed_s_it)
reversed_s = ''.join(reversed_list)
```

But when I try to create a string from the iterator directly, it just gives a string representation of the iterator, if I do this:

```py
s = 'abcde'
reversed_s_it = reversed(s)
reversed_s = str(reversed_s_it)
```

`reversed_s` will give a string representation of the iterator instead of iterating the iterator to create a string.

```py
print(reversed_s)
```

Output

```
<reversed object at 0x10c3dedf0>
```

Furthermore

```py
print(reversed_s == 'edcba')
```

Output

```
False
```

**Therefore, I just want to know if there is a Pythonic way to create a string from an iterator?**

Comment: What's wrong with `''.join(reversed(s))`?

Comment: @chepner, I just don't feel good about using an extra space for creating an extra list to construct a string, I'm not sure if there is a better way

Comment: Iterators can be materialized as lists or tuples by using the list() or tuple() constructor functions. So it is hard to imagine there’s another way to skip this step.

Comment: String is an iterable object in python.  and type(reversed_s) shows it as a str object what do you mean when you say "reversed_s is still an iterator"

Comment: "reversed_s is still an iterator." no, it isn't. It's a `str` object. In any case, you can do `''.join(reversed(s))` **but** that will still create a list underneath the hood, but it is "directly" from an iterator.

Comment: @SandeepPolamuri, sorry, it seems I am wrong and `reversed_s` is a string, but when I try to print it, it shows as `<reversed object at 0x10c3dedf0>`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, I just found out that I was wrong, but when when I try to print it, it shows as `<reversed object at 0x10c3dedf0>`, why is that?

Comment: @SiAce because that's the string representation of that iterator, which is what you asked for when you did `str(reversed_s_it)`, the same as any object, which just happens to be the default `__str__` implementation inherited from `object`, so, for example, `class Foo: pass` then `print(Foo())` will give you something similar.

Comment: @SiAce print(type(reversed_s)) shows as <type 'str'> in both python2 and python3 compilers.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, I see, now I understand that the reversed_s is a string whose content is `<reversed object at 0x10c3dedf0>`. I was confused at first.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reverse a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931092/reverse-a-string-in-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`''.join` itself only needs an iterable; you don't have to create a list first.

```
>>> ''.join(reversed(s))
'edcba'
```

However, there's nothing wrong with `s[::-1]`; in fact, it's quite a bit faster than using `''.join` to concatenated the elements from the `reversed` object.

Comment: Oh, thanks, didn't know about that. By the way, what's the time complexity of `join()`?

Comment: **NOTE** implementation detail, `.join` materializes a list underneath the hood anyway.